# Copy or move from nth level subfolder to another directory or folder

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, copy, move

We have a software that adds a `wav` file and put it on a folder by its date which is buried under several subfolders.

For example:

```
home/user/music/group1/person1/todays date/wav file

home/user/music/group1/person1/yesterdays date/wav file

home/user/music/group1/person2/todays date/wav file

home/user/music/group1/person2/yesterdays date/wav file
```

Also, the person(n) folder is dynamic which means its created automatically if the software founds someone using that device and creates that folder. So for example, if a new user is using the software it will create `home/user/music/group1/person3/`.

How do I move or copy starting from the person(n) folder and move them to a new folder like `home/user/new/person1..` `home/user/new/person2..`

Since the person(n) folder is dynamic I could not just do command like cp person1 newdirectory
What i did is find all wav files under group1 folder and cp to new folder but it copies the full path.

`find /home/user/music/group1 -name "*.wav" -type f -exec cp --parents \{\} /home/user/new \;`

If i remove `--parents`  it will only copy the files to new folder. how do I copy starting from the person(n) folder to new folder?

Comment: So in effect, you just need to extract the person(n) element out of the path. As you know the structure of the parent directories, you can then so a standard copy of one directory to another?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @RamanSailopal, i got it to work with `find /home/user/music/group1/ -name "person*" -type d -exec cp -pR {}/ /home/user/new \;`

Comment: If `n` in `person` is an int/digit, you could probably use, `person[0-9]*`

Comment: @Jetchisel yes, n is a digit, i'll give your suggestion a go, thanks!